# android nullpointer when setting spinner adapter

Tags: android, spinner

I get this error:

```
14:03:44.170    322 hnlapp.hairdresser  ERROR   AndroidRuntime  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
14:03:44.170    322 hnlapp.hairdresser  ERROR   AndroidRuntime  java.lang.NullPointerException
14:03:44.170    322 hnlapp.hairdresser  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at hnlapp.hairdresser.Page_Calendar.onOptionsItemSelected(Page_Calendar.java:2824)
```

When attempting to do this:

```
spinusertype.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

In this code:

```
Spinner spinusertype      =       (Spinner)  findViewById(R.id.spinnerUserType);
String[] userTypes = new String[]{"user","hairdresser","admin"};
                            ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, userTypes);


                            spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                            spinusertype.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

Comment: so check if spinusertype is not null

Comment: did you declare the spinner's id

Comment: see the edit above the code , I did declare the spinner and it has a valid id etc.

Comment: did you declare a valid spinner's id in your layout file ?

Comment: @Mr.Me , I ran in debugging mode and stepped into that code and spinusertype is null ... but why ?

Comment: have you implemented onOptionsItemSelected(Page_Calendar.java:2824)?

Comment: no , did not think it was necessary... let me do that and will let you know the outcome.

Comment: Ok , I implemented  onOptionsItemSelected but I get the same error.

Comment: tbo, I mean I implemented onItemSelectedListener. The onOptionsItemSelected I have implemented long before to use for the options menu. My code lies inside of there.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by doing this:

```
 Spinner spinusertype            =       (Spinner)  dialog.findViewById(R.id.spinnerUserType);
```

in stead of this:

```
 Spinner spinusertype            =       (Spinner)  findViewById(R.id.spinnerUserType);
```

I have no idea why it would make a difference because the spinnner's id is unique.

Comment: The dialog it self doesn't have a layout item with the id you're using , but the activity's content view does , which explains it